# How to apply method to AirDatepicker in my custom js file?

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I have a AirDatepicker  v3.3.5 defined in app.js file as :

```
window.dateRangePicker = new AirDatepicker('.date-range', {
    range: true,
    maxDate: new Date(),
    multipleDatesSeparator: ' - '
});
```

Looking at https://air-datepicker.com/examples docs
I need in my custom form.js to add to apply onSelect and update methods like

```
dpMin = new AirDatepicker('#el1', {
    onSelect({date}) {
        dpMax.update({
            minDate: date
        })
    }
})
```

But I failed it, as I tried :

```
window.dateRangePicker.onSelect({date}) {
    ...

};
```

But I got error :

```
Expecting new line or semicolon
```

Which syntax is valid ?

Comment: I don't think they have onSelect method on assigned object. onSelect method is present inside as options.

Comment: inside as options in the code of   app.js  where I declare window.dateRangePicker var ? I can not use it in  form.js(I need to use vars which are declared in this file) ?

Comment: I am saying you can access window.dateRangePicker object once initialise. But they don't have onSelect method on that object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, Document says we can pass the `onSelect` method inside the options at the time of initialisation but they don't have onSelect method on that created object itself.

When i checked and traced the assigned object i find that we can utilise the functions exposed as part of created object. We can assign the method after initialisation like below.

You can try something like this.

```
window.dateRangePicker.opts.onSelect = ({date}) => {
  console.log(date);
}
```